# Getting individual counts of last three distinct rows in column of data retrieved from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns several rows of data (in `datetime` format) of a single column obtained by performing `JOINS` on multiple `SQL Tables`. The Data obtained is a DateTime type and now I just want the individual count of latest three dates probably the count of lat three distinct dates as it sorted from earliest to latest.

SQL Query

```
SELECT  
 ST.EffectiveDate
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
 ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
 ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
```

The above query returns around 200 rows of data but I want the count for each of three latest dates possibly bottom three

Comment: He did say the count of each of the 3 latest dates.  Reading his question right, if latest 3 dates are 7/18, 7/19, and 7/20, he wants to get a count of each of them.

Comment: @TinyHaitian Yes.. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with `top` and `group by`:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ST.EffectiveDate, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Person.Contact C INNER JOIN
     Sales.SalesPerson SP
     ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID FULL OUTER JOIN
     Sales.SalesTerritory ST
     ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
GROUP BY ST.EffectiveDate
ORDER BY ST.EffectiveDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

added another query to get the latest 3 distinct dates

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
 ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
 ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
WHERE ST.effectivedate in (select distinct top 3 effectivedate 
                          from salesterritory 
                          order by effectivedate desc)
```

Or if you need to see the counts for the 3 dates broken out

```
SELECT st.effectivedate, count(1)
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
 ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
 ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
WHERE ST.effctivedate in (select distinct top 3 effectivedate 
                          from salesterritory 
                          order by effectivedate desc)
GROUP BY st.effectivedate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the analytic [`RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function. This query will number the latest date as 1, the next latest as 2, and so forth:

```
SELECT
  ST.EffectiveDate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ST.EffectiveDate DESC) AS DateRank
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
```

You can't use the ranked value in the WHERE clause, so you'll need to take the query above and make it a subquery or a common table expression (CTE).

**Subquery version**:

```
SELECT EffectiveDate, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST.EffectiveDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ST.EffectiveDate DESC) AS DateRank
  FROM Person.Contact C
  INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
  FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
) DateList
WHERE DateRank <= 3
GROUP BY EffectiveDate
```

**CTE version**:

```
WITH DateList AS (
  SELECT
    ST.EffectiveDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ST.EffectiveDate DESC) AS DateRank
  FROM Person.Contact C
  INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
  FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
)
SELECT EffectiveDate, COUNT(*)
FROM DateList
WHERE DateRank <= 3
GROUP BY EffectiveDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing SQL Server 2005 and above, you could even try this:

```
 ;with cte as 
 (
 SELECT  
  ST.EffectiveDate
 FROM Person.Contact C
 INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
  ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
 FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
  ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
 )
 Select EffectiveDate, count(1)
 from cte
 where EffectiveDate in (select distinct top 3 effectivedate 
                      from cte
                      order by EffectiveDate desc)
 group by EffectiveDate
```

Though untested, it should work; it my be unnecessarily elaborate though.

Comment: @EdGibbs post for the cte may actually be a bit cleaner than mine.  I forgot about the rank idea.